# How to display video with alpha channel

Tags: android, animation, video, alpha

I have a huge videofile (800x1095 pixels, 200frames) that i need to show on top of the background of my application.
I can't figur out how to use a video with an alpha channel in android... or if it is possible. The app is not targetet to lower sdks then 17.

I have tried to do it as a png sequence,- but as one would expect,- the device ran out of memory.